# List View onItemclickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have a ListView whose id is android:id="@android:id/list"

and i have a custom cursor Adapter in which i inflate my custom Linear Layout
My custom LinearLayout has an image view on left side and textview on right side

I am able to populate the data on the list view but i am not able to get setonItemClickListener working

```
PlaylistScreen.this.lv = getListView();



        MusicCursorAdapter musicCursor = new MusicCursorAdapter(PlaylistScreen.this, cursor, tracks);
        //PlaylistScreen.this.setListAdapter(musicCursor);
        PlaylistScreen.this.lv.setAdapter(musicCursor);

        PlaylistScreen.this.lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Log.d("Item Click","+++++++++");
                             })
                     })


           but i am not able to get this in logcat
```

Comment: Try adding Listener to the whole of the rowView inside `Adapter` in `getView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I acheived this by overriding **getView** method in cursor adapter and implementing onclicklistener for a view. Thanks guys for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Are you in debug mode?

> Log.d(string,string)

works in debug mode. Eventually try:

> Log.w("","")

.

Comment: yes i am in debug mode and also i did add toast even it is not working in my custom linearlayout i set the parent layout focussable=true as mentioned on many posts but still it is not working

Comment: Do you extend your class from Activity

Answer (score 0):

You must have used an adapter..If u have an Listener there..Then setOnItemClickListener wont work.

Comment: yes, then how can i implement onclicklistener plus i want onclick on the layout not on text view or anything like that